# Merge two sorted linked lists - Python implementation - wrong/incomplete output

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge, linked-list, sortedlist

I am trying to solve this [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/) question - Merge two sorted linked lists

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:


        current1 = l1 #pointer - towards the head of list1
        prev1 = ListNode("") #just before current1
        prev1.next = l1

        current2 = l2 #pointer - towards the head of list2
        prev2 = ListNode("") #just before current2
        prev2.next = l2

        while prev1.next is not None:
            if current1.val <= current2.val:

                if current1.next is None:
                    prev1.next = current2
                else:
                    prev1.next = current1
                    if current1.next is None:
                        continue
                    else:
                        current1 = current1.next

            else:
                if current2.next is None:
                    prev1.next = current1
                else:
                    prev1.next = current2
                    if current2.next is None:
                        continue
                    else:
                        current2 = current2.next
            prev1 = prev1.next

        #if prev1.next is None: #i think some code/condition has to be added here since it's not tracing the last element left - i.e. largest element

        return l1
```

For the given test case, I am getting the **wrong output**:

> > > input - [1,2,4] and [1,3,4]
> > >
> > > my output - [1,1,2,3,4]
> > >
> > > expected output - [1,1,2,3,4,4]

The code seems to work fine but I think I am missing some condition and not able to terminate/parse till the very end.

Edit (Update)

I am running this code now - made some changes to the above code:

```
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:

        current1 = l1 #towards head of list
        prev1 = ListNode("")
        prev1.next = l1
        output = l1


        current2 = l2 #pointer - towards the head of list2
        prev2 = ListNode("") #just before current2
        prev2.next = l2

        if current1 is None and current2 is not None:
            prev1 = current2
        elif current1 is not None and current2 is None:
            prev1 = current1
        elif current1 is None and current2 is None:
            return None
        elif current1 is not None and current2 is not None:

            #traverse and check for the two lists
            while prev1.next is not None:
                if current1.val <= current2.val:
                    prev1.next = current1
                    prev1 = prev1.next
                    if current1.next is not None:
                        current1 = current1.next
                        prev1.next != None
                    else:
                        prev1.next = current2
                        prev1 = prev1.next

                else:
                    prev1.next = current2
                    prev1 = prev1.next
                    if current2.next is not None:
                        current2 = current2.next
                        prev1.next != None
                    else:
                        prev1.next = current1
                        prev1 = prev1.next

            return output
```

Now I am not getting the correct/expected output. It is, however, working for the **above-mentioned test case**.

> > > Input: [] and [0]
> > >
> > > Output: []
> > >
> > > Expected: [0]

I think this is considering None as 0 and not sure what to add to the condition to make this code work.

Answer (score 2):

Verified solution (using [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge)):

```
from heapq import merge

class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

class Solution(object):
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1, l2):
        """
        :type l1: ListNode
        :type l2: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """

        def iter_list(l):
            v = l
            while v:
                yield v
                v = v.next

        def create_nodes():
            l = ListNode(None)
            val = yield l
            l.val = val
            while True:
                val = yield
                l.next = ListNode(val)
                l = l.next

        creator = create_nodes()
        rv = next(creator)
        for v in merge(iter_list(l1), iter_list(l2), key=lambda k: k.val):
            creator.send(v.val)

        return None if rv.val is None else rv

 # [1,2,4] and [1,3,4]
l1 = ListNode(1)
l1.next = ListNode(2)
l1.next.next = ListNode(4)

l2 = ListNode(1)
l2.next = ListNode(3)
l2.next.next = ListNode(4)

def print_list(l):
    v = l
    while v:
        print(v.val)
        v = v.next

new_list_node = Solution().mergeTwoLists(l1, l2)
print_list(new_list_node)
```

Prints:

```
1
1
2
3
4
4
```

On `leetcode` it was classified as **Success** ([link](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/289269685/)):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be much simpler:

```
from itertools import chain

lst1 = [1,2,4]
lst2 = [1,3,4]

output = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(lst1, lst2)))
```

If you don't want to use `itertools` you can use this approach:

```
output = [x for t in zip(lst1, lst2) for x in t]
```

Comment: Wow. I have to check their (chain, zip) implementations/details before trying to understand them. I have never imported **itertools** before.

Comment: @Sanya Check my other solution without the use of `itertools`. Also please remember to mark my answer as accepted if you like it

Comment: Thank you so much for providing another alternative. But will this work for linked lists?

Comment: will it work if the linked lists are of unequal lengths?

Comment: it doesn't work at all, the question is to merge 2 SORTED lists, it means that order should be persisted, but you are just merging 2 iterables with output that happens to be sorted

Answer (score 1):

In the above mentioned code there is a discrepancy in the logic.
For instance:

```
if(current1.val <= current.val2):
    if(current1.next is None):
        #this is wrong as you are skipping the present current1 val 
        prev1.next =current2
```

It should be

```
if(current1.val <= current.val2):
    if(current1.next is None):
        prev1.next = current1
        prev1 = prev1.next
        prev1.next =current2
```

Same for the second end of the list condition. That is the reason the ending value `4` is being erased. Hope this helps.

Comment: oh got it! thanks for reading the code. Also, can you help me with this test case - [] and [0]. My output is coming out to be [] whereas it should be [0]. Should I explicitly give 0 in the conditions? as I give for None?